# Making circles move around racetrack at different speeds. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

i want to make my 2 circles move around my racetrack at different speeds using this method of coding, however both circles are acting upon 1 of the lines of code instead of independant of each other.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

let angle =0;

function draw() {
  background(0,255,0);
  stroke(0);
  fill(150);
  ellipse(200, 200, 200, 100);
  fill(0,255,0);
  ellipse(200, 200, 125, 50);
  
  noFill(0);
  stroke(255,255,0);
  ellipse(200, 200, 160, 70);
  ellipse(200, 200, 165, 75);
  
  
//red circle  
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  let centreX = width/2;
  let centreY = height/2
  let x = 85 * cos(angle);
  let y = 47.5 * sin(angle);
  
  fill(255,0,0);
  ellipse(centreX + x, centreY + y, 10, 10);
 
  
  angle += 1; 
  
//blue circle
  
  let centreA = width/2;
  let centreB = height/2
  let a = 65 * cos(angle);
  let b = 30 * sin(angle);
  
  fill(0,0,255);
  ellipse(centreA + a, centreB + b, 10, 10);
  
  angle += 2;

  }
```

Both of the circles move on angle += 2 when i only want the blue circle to move at that speed and want the red one to remain at angle +=1. Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: They're both using the same variable. Try having two: `let angleOne = 0; let angleTwo = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You need them to be completely independent of each other. While most of your variables are independent, your angles are the same variable, meaning they're moving at the same `angle += 1; angle += 2;` every time the code is run. To prevent that you need them to have 2 different angles.